# Debugging and Testing a Web Application Efficiently

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-debugging

I have written a web application which I am trying to test but I am finding that some of the things that I am doing are really repetitive and inefficient. For example, I might want to test just the reporting component of the application but in order to access the reporting section, you are required to log-in. I find myself logging in all the time just to test a completely unrelated component. What are some strategies that I can use to bypass these kind of constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Unit test these functionalities. This way you can automate repetitive tasks.
It also helps to improve your code quality by doing so ;)

A link to get you started : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx